# How to find argmax/argmin in only selected indices of a Pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, indices, argmax

I have a **distance tensor**

```
tensor([ 5,  10,  2,  3,  4], device='cuda:0')
```

And a **indices tensor**

```
tensor([ 0,  2,  3], device='cuda:0')
```

I want to **find argmax** of the distance tensor but only **on the subset** of indices specified by the indices tensor.

In this example, I would be looking at 0th, 2nd and 3rd elements of distance tensor (values 5, 2, 3) and returning the index 0 (the biggest value - 5 is on the 0th place in the distance tensor)

```
tensor([ 0], device='cuda:0')
```

Is something like this feasible without the use of for cycles?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example. You can check that the maximum `dist` value for the selected subset of items is at index zero, and the final output tensor contains value zero too. Note that as we are using 1D tensors, `dim` argument in `torch.index_select` is zero.

```py
import torch

dist = torch.randn(5, 1)
#tensor([[ 0.3392],
#        [ 0.4472],
#        [ 0.1398],
#        [-1.0379],
#        [ 0.2950]])


idx = torch.tensor([0,2,3])
#tensor([0, 2, 3])
```

Just using `max` function and tensor filtering:

```py
max_val = torch.max(torch.index_select(dist, 0, idx)).item()
#0.33918169140815735
(dist == max_val).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
#tensor([0])
```

Comment: The direct argmax approach appears not to be working. It gives the arg of the indices, not of the original array. The max function&filtering works fine though.

Comment: you right, I will modify the answer